# ember-cli-build.js | set broccoli's params depending on environmnet

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I tried to search in google this but without the correct answer if I need to do.

It's a simple question I have my ember-cli-build.js

```
  /*jshint node:true*/
  /* global require, module */
  var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

  module.exports = function(defaults) {
    var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
      storeConfigInMeta: false,
      minifyJS: {
        enabled: false
      },
      minifyCSS: {
        enabled: false
      }
    });

    return app.toTree();
  };
```

And I want change the value of minifyJS or minifyCSS depending on whether I am running ember in production or dev - how can achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer applies to Ember 2.x.x and was written as of 2.15.

In your `ember-cli-build.js` you can do `EmberApp.env()` to get the environment. You could also do `process.env.EMBER_ENV` but the first option is in the [Ember CLI Docs](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#source-maps), so I'd go with that personally.

Example:

```
  var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

  module.exports = function(defaults) {
    var enableMin = (EmberApp.env() === 'production');
    var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
      storeConfigInMeta: false,
      minifyJS: {
        enabled: enableMin
      },
      minifyCSS: {
        enabled: enableMin
      }
    });


    return app.toTree();
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

According to EmberCLI docs: [Fingerprinting and CDN URLs](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls) also `app.env` property should be available and the following code should be fine, too:

```
module.exports = function (defaults) {

  const app = new EmberApp(defaults, {});

  if (app.env === 'development') {
      // do something specific for dev
  } else if (app.env === 'production') {
      // do something specific for prod
   }
};
```

Note:
`app.env` holds `"test"` when building for testing purposes.